# Does __attribute__((optimize(0))) apply "recursively"?

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes

Say I want to use a function to measure runtime, I want to avoid the compiler optimizing away expressions just because it thinks they do nothing (they don't, except that I want to measure how long they take to compute). Instead of doing weird gimmicks like adding it up into another variable etc., I found out about `__atribute__((optimize(0)))` in GCC. However, say I have this code:

```
__attribute__((optimize(0))) void test(int n) {
    while (n--) {
        foo();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Timer::measure(test).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

Would the attribute prevent the compiler from optimizing code inside the function foo() as well? I'm really just trying to test some runtime and reliably and with relative easy prevent the compiler from removing code completely (I want it to optimize the code as good as it can, but not remove it because it doesn't do anything!).

Does that make any sense? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured I could do an experiment (why didn't I think of that sooner), here's what I did:

```
// toggle this
// __attribute__((optimize(0)))
void waste_time() { for (unsigned i = 100000; i--; ); }

// always leave this on
__attribute__((optimize(0)))
void test() {
    for (unsigned i = 1000; i--; ) {
        waste_time();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Timer::measure(test).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

What I found with -O3:

```
waste_time no optimizations: 196.972ms  (obviously the loop is not optimized)
waste_time w/ optimizations: 0.001995ms (loop is optimized)
```

For me this makes it very clear, that `__attribute__` does not "propagate" to nested function calls, so waste_time() still will be optimized even though test() has the attribute specified.

Comment: On a sidenote: I have had the experience, that even __attribute((optimize(0))) didn't prevent the compiler from not compiling "dead" code.

Comment: hey! I am thinking to find a way to "propagate" this attribute. Do you happen to know a way of doing so?

Comment: @lllllllllllll When I last tested this, as is already stated, the attribute does not apply to functions called within the function. You will simply need to explicitly put the attribute to all functions you wish to do this for, I don't know of another solution.